# No HDMI output after shutting down RPI

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display

Flash Raspbian on 32GB SD card.

Everything works fine when first start.
After I shutdown it using `sudo shutdown -h now` and take off usb power..

Suddenly, HDMI output broken down, no output on LCD at all.

Please help..

Comment: Is that not to be expected? You cut all power to the pi so how would you see a picture on the screen?

Comment: Side not: You should make yourself an alias to shutdown with something simpler like "sd". Just run the command "sudo nano .bashrc" and add the line alias sd='sudo shutdown -h now'

Comment: Can you please look over your grammar and be more specific in your question?

Comment: See this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi

Comment: Do you mean the HDMI output is broken when you turn it back on again?

Answer (score 2):

when the power is disconnected from the raspberry pi or is shut down, all peripherals such as HDMI are no longer usable because the source, being the raspberry pi and it's data is no longer on and transmitting data to the HDMI output.