# Change output to HDMI after tv has turned off

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force the Raspberry Pi to turn on HDMI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi)

I have a Pi that is connected to my TV via hdmi.

My pi acts primarily as a server, and its turned on all the time for this reason. My problem is that when my tv turns off, and then on again the PI does not resume sending to the tv. The sceeen is just going at it with "No signal".

Is there any way to get the PI to change back to HDMI when the TV turns back on?

Or, alternatively, just keep sending to the HDMI output no matter if it detects a TV or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [How do I force the Raspberry Pi to turn on HDMI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi). The /boot/config.txt file applies to the RaspberryPi itself, not to the installed OS so the configuration explained here should solve this problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm...