# Continously running presentation "pauses" after one hour

Tags: raspbian, display, gui

I have a Raspberry Pi that is connected to a TV on its HDMI Port and to the Network over Ethernet.

After boot it automatically logs into the GUI with the pi user and automatically starts a Presentation in Libre Office. That presentation should run indefinetely.

So far this works well but after one hour (+/- 3 Minutes) the slides stop changing. It just displays the same slide forever.

In this state i can login to the running session with VNC and press the space bar, then the presentation continues changing slides.

### What I already tried to fix the Problem

#### Disable Screen Blanking #1

I disabled screen blanking in the Raspberry Pi Configuration Dialog as described [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-disable-screen-blanking/) in section *Disabling Screen Blanking using the Raspberry Pi Desktop*

#### Disable Screen Blanking #2

As #1 did not solve the problem I tried editing `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` as described [here](https://techedemic.com/2014/08/04/raspberry-pi-disable-screensaver-blank-screen/)

```
# Edit the /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc file and add the following three lines at the bottom of the file
xset s off         # don't activate screensaver
xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device
```

#### Disable Console Blanking

I already thought this will not help as i'm not on the console but tried it anyway.
I added the next lines in `/etc/rc.local` as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/raspberry-loosing-hdmi-output-after-a-period-of-time)

```
# turn off console blanking
setterm -blank 0
```

#### Disabling Screensaver by installing xscreensaver

As I read a lot during my searches i installed xscreensaver and disabled the Screensaver using the Desktop Settings Dialog in Preferences -> Screensaver

### Conclusion

The Raspberry Pi doesn't seem to freeze or something as I'm able to connect to it with VNC and force the continuation of the presentation with the space bar.

I'm out of ideas what else to try. Does anyone know of some logfile I possibly can find clues in? Or how else to diagnose the Problem further?

I don't even know if it's something on system level that causes the "pause" or if Libre Office is to blame.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Others reported that running libre office on 64-bit solves this.
Images here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/
Post here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=248757

Answer (score 0):

Installing 64-bit (as pointed out by @A.J.Bauer in the comments) did solve the Problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).