# HDMI hisses when turned on before TV

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi

If I turn my Pi on before the TV then I get a hissing/static noise until I yank the HDMI cable and plug it in again. If I turn my TV on during boot it will hiss, but seems to come right once XBMC launches. If I turn my TV on after XBMC has launched then it does not correct itself.

I have forced HDMI to turn on ([How do I force the Raspberry Pi to turn on HDMI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi/2171#2171)) and am running Raspbmc.

Comment: What is hissing? the TV, the cable, or the Pi?

Comment: The hissing is coming through on the TV speakers, but I am confident that the Pi is causing it.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be using the `hdmi_force_edid_audio=1` option (assuming that your TV can decode DTS etc. coming in through the HDMI lead). If it doesn't then using `hdmi_force_edid_audio=0` might help.