# No audio on Xbian connected to an AV receiver via HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, kodi, xbian

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Xbian and XBMC installed that **works perfect through HDMI when I connect it to the TV set**. Video and audio are nice, but I've tried to set up it with my AV receiver without success.

The Raspberry Pi (Xbian and XBMC again) is now connected to the AV Receiver through the "HDMI In" input, and the AV Receiver "HDMI Out" goes to a 720p projector. Although the video works, **there's no audio anywhere**.

I've tried to apply previous solutions, such as [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi/2171#2171) in which the **config.txt** should have the following lines

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

And even tried **forcing EDID Audio**:

```
# HDMI Force EDID Audio
# Pretends all audio formats are supported by display, allowing passthrough of
# DTS/AC3 even when not reported as supported.
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
```

But with no success.

One more thing. The AV Receiver (Sony SDR-K890 with a 6.1 surround system) has two HDMI inputs. The one I try to use, "Video 2", should be the one working.

I currently use the other one, labeled "DVD", that **allows me to connect an audio cable** from the 3.5mm RPi connector to 2xRCA (Left/Right) connectors on the DVD Audio part of the AV Receiver.

If I do that and change XBMC audio settings to Analog / 2.0 **I get sound**. But this, of course, is not the ideal solution. I'd like to take advantage of HDMI and surround sound. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on the latest firmware? Have you tried specifying in XMBC the speaker configuration?

Comment: Yes to both. I've tried everything I've thought of in the XBMC audio settings without success

Answer (score 1):

After testing all OS's  for the best audio & video solution for the Pi, I find the OpenELEC Operating System - Kodi Version 5.0.8 Optimised for the RPi 2 is superior.

It is provisioned to run HD movies, YOUTUBE videos, DVD's, all streaming media, all with HARDWARE separation of audio via HDMI & aux(3.5mm) plug, pumping out digital audio simultaneously.
Which can also be sent seamlessly, from you iPhone to your screen & audio via Airplay.

When you plug in  your AV Receiver (Sony SDR-K890 with a 6.1 surround system) into the aux(3.5mm) AND have separate audio control on the monitor via HDMI imput..... You will see why the RPi is incomparable !

Please see my post: [Open Elec phantom screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33523/open-elec-phantom-screen)

Answer (score 1):

If you want audio you must get a digital audio cable from the TV/Projector back to your surround system.

However, OpenELEC doesn't support 6.1, just 5.1.  With 7.0 recordings I don't hear the voices of the actors.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.