# Open Elec phantom screen

Tags: wifi, raspbmc, wireless, openelec, software-recommendation

I was using some of the lesser used features on the RPI Open Elec operating system. Specifically, the Navi-x environment. All features here can have long loading times. After being distracted, I came back 12 hours later to see an image on the screen, of an unlocked text message screen, of an iphone, that was connected to my wifi home network at that time. After checking with my son's girlfriend (the owner of the iphone,) she said she had sent a multi-media text message, around that time.
Can anyone tell me what happened here?

Comment: Thanks for the Badge !  Come on Open Elec'perts;  this i is the most puzzling issue I've ever seen....

Answer (score 2):

--This has got to be one of the least known BEST features of the RPI.--

You can actually broadcast music, video, YOUTUBE from an iPhone to your RPi screen effortlessly!

By default, "Airplay" an Apple product is what's going on here.  Quoted from the Apple website is this reference: "AirPlay lets you wirelessly stream what’s on your iOS devices and Mac to your HDTV and speakers.  Or  mirror exactly what’s on your display to the big screen. Guests can even easily share their content with peer-to-peer AirPlay".

I'm not sure Apple knows how easy, as in my example, where no request, no handshake, no knowledge by either party was needed to display an iPhone text message screen...

After investigating the iPhone that mirrored the message to my Raspberry Pi's TV screen, I found in the iPhone's slide-up settings screen, an entry for OpenElec output !

Comment: Its probably [XBMC's support of airplay](http://kodi.wiki/view/AirPlay) that is going on here (as [here](http://blog.thestateofme.com/2013/01/07/airplay-on-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/)) :) I think airplay/drop/whatever have security settings which vary from ok to wacky, which is probably it is so easy to connect.