# RPi web browsers that work on YouTube

Tags: streaming-video, web-browsers

Have tried about 4 different web browsers for the RPi2 as of 7/25/15.

- When you go to the YouTube web site with **Chromium**, it says needs Flash plug in and has install bar. Clicking on the install bar crashes Chromium. Yes, I installed Chromium after `apt-get update` and `apt-get install chromium`.
- The **Epiphany** browser will play video, but has a big start button in the middle of the screen which does not go away when the video starts playing.
- **IceWeasel** seems to play the video, but is a slow as can be and useless. It keeps running after you close the window for it.

Help me out guys and girls. I need to watch YouTube videos to learn this stuff, it is the fastest and easiest way.

Comment: Tried midori ??

Comment: Personally on the pi I like using [yt-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and then watching them with [omxplayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer) -- full screen, hardware accelerated, no glitches.  That doesn't involve a web browser though, so it is a bit of a drag if what you want to do is browse youtube and sample things.

Comment: I was going to say `youtube-dl` as well, if only that HTML5 video playback is still spotty on the Pi.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the best YouTube Pi experience is accomplished with the Epiphany browser. The start button is ever present, but on Pi2  I have experienced most youtube videos to play well except music videos. If the video will play, the play button will stop blinking within 30 seconds, right clicking, then reload will work, after another video selection has been made. Pause will not work; & any mouse movements after the video has started affects the sound...
For peak peformance, navigate to https://www.youtube.com/html5 & check off use HTML5 player.

Comment: In response to wiget: OpenElec, the full package, will play YT, seamlessly, WITHOUT any RED PLAY BUTTON during playback, but that's the least of it; I'm fortunate enough to have a dedicated Pi solely for OpenElec because I discovered "AirPlay" will allow you to stream ANY content from your iPhone to your Pi..Please see my previous post :   http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33523/open-elec-phantom-screen

Answer (score 3):

Kodi (kodi-standalone) plays YT movies well.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to implement a solution using OpenMAX and Qt but I'm still pretty far from a usable result. This is however the [current state](http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.it/2015/12/playing-youtube-videos-on-raspberry-pi.html). But this technique is worth investigation if you want to invest time.