# Is it possible to connect to a display port?

Tags: hdmi, video, display, screen

I bought a HDMI to DP cable to connect my Raspberry Pi 2 to a screen with Display Port.

[image: HDMI to DP cable]

Unfortunately I get no output on the screen.

Is it possible to connect the Raspberry Pi 2 to a screen with display port using this cable? What would I need to configure to achieve this?

> **Note**:
>   I get video output on my TV while using a plain HDMI cable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this cable actually is a DP-to-HDMI cable not HDMI-to-DP, mind the direction. While there are DP ports able to support HMDI signals (DisplayPort Dual-mode) HDMI does not support DP, so a simple (passive) cable cannout simply reroute some signal lines on different connectors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That cable is most likely a DisplayPort-to-HDMI cable not a HDMI-to-DisplayPort cable (mind the direction). While there are DP ports able to support HMDI signals (DisplayPort Dual-mode) HDMI does not support DP directly. Since HDMI data transmission is very different from DP there will be no simple (passive) cable that just re-routes some signal lines on the different connectors.

[DisplayPort@Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort):

> The DisplayPort signal is not compatible with DVI or HDMI. However,
> Dual-mode DisplayPorts are designed to transmit a single-link DVI or
> HDMI 1.2/1.4 protocol across the interface through the use of an
> external passive adapter that selects the desired signal and converts
> the electrical signaling from LVDS to TMDS.

and [HDMI@Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Relationship_with_DisplayPort):

> DisplayPort ports can be made so that they are compatible with
> single-link DVI and HDMI 1.4.[200] Compatibility is achieved with
> DisplayPort Dual-mode ports, which are marked with the ++DP logo,
> using attached passive adapters.

So while these cables can connect a DP appliance to a HDMI display it's not possible to connect a HDMI appliance (such as the RPi) to a DP display.

Comment: "Display Port Kabel auf HDMI" - I missed this small detail even though it was in the ebay item title ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You may try to force HDMI output by editing /boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2171/21993)