# Raspberry Pi 2 Boot problem

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-2, boot-issues

I have some strange boot behavior on some of my Raspberry Pi 2.

Setup is as follows:

- RPi2 HDMI connected to TV
- RPi2 Power in connected to USB port on TV
- Ethernet connected

I have a lot of these setups working fine, USB from TV gives 1-1.5A depending on TV Model but most of the time it's always the same model (should give 1.5A).

Now most of those setups work i.e. when I turn on the TV the Raspberry Pi 2 gets power via USB from the TV and boots up but in some setups when I turn on the TV the Raspberry Pi does not boot at all.

The PowerLED (red) and the ActivityLED (green) go on for about a second or two when I power on the TV, then go off again and finally the PowerLED goes on again and stays on but no activity on the SD Card and the RPi does not boot.

And now the REALLY STRANGE part:
When I have such a setup that does not work and I disconnect HDMI, turn on the TV and after that plug in the HDMI cable into the Raspberry Pi it works.

Any good ideas what the problem could be that in some of all these similar setups it won't boot but boots fine if HDMI is not connected?

Comment: Try using the solution mentioned in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi

Comment: Thanks for your suggest but those config values are already in my config.txt - in my case it's the other way round than in the thread you linked, its not booting when HDMI is connected but booting without HDMI connected and I connect it later. So HDMI hotplug works as expected.

Comment: @p9teufel: What kind of power supply are you using? It sounds like the device doesn't have enough power to power both the HDMI output and main board.

Comment: I've been having issues with my RPi the other way - if I start my RPi without HDMI connected, then it won't start ( or at least no HDMI output if I connect HDMI later ), but if I start RPi with HDMI connected - it works OK. Must be something with HDMI / auto settings?