# Force HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, screen, touchscreen

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and a LCD

I have no problem with LCD but i want to switch HDMI for video output . i tried to add these line to `config.txt` :

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
display_default_lcd=0
```

but i can't use HDMI even by those codes

anyone have idea? i used raspberry pi about two years ago and i can't remember how to fix this

**Update**: I used [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi) question before

Comment: Are you editing the `/boot/config.txt` file? If so, it should work with only the following changes: `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` use HDMI mode even if no HDMI monitor is detected<br>
`hdmi_drive=2` set to normal HDMI mode (with sound if supported and enabled) If your HDMI monitor doesn't support sound, try setting `hdmi_drive=1` since it's possible that the RPi's protocol communications over HDMI with your monitor are determining that sound is not supported and the RPi is disabling the HDMI output.

Comment: You didn't specify exactly which file you were editing. Are you editing /boot/config.txt ? I'll edit my answer to provide more suggestions.

Comment: Are you using NOOBS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force the Raspberry Pi to turn on HDMI?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/how-do-i-force-the-raspberry-pi-to-turn-on-hdmi)

Comment: yes of course :| @BartmanEH

Comment: Yes ... NOOBS @joan

Comment: NOOBS is a bit funny (I don't use it).  Check its documentation for how to edit the correct config.txt.  I believe you have to hold the shift key down during boot to get the recovery screen.  There should be an option to edit the correct config.txt from that screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with `con2fbmap 1 1` or `(play with 0 and 1 ones` for console.

For starting X, if you used config with multiple layouts e.g. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/fbtft.conf` (like http://pastebin.com/3wdEU9hw ), you can use sth like `startx -- -layout hdmi`.