# Is it possible to use use a 4x3 monitor

Tags: display

I have a 1280 x 1024 monitor I want to use as display. I have an HDMI to DVI adapter. What must I configure to make it work?

Comment: [Everything you wanted to know about video options in config.txt but were too afraid to search for](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

Comment: A 4x3 is 4 pixels by 3 pixels, how small do you want this screen?

Comment: @BlackOps-9-Elite 4x3 is the _aspect ratio_ of the screen, not the pixels. In other words, the ratio of width to height.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to configure anything. Because you said you have a HDMI to DVI adapter, I am assuming your monitor is DVI. So just plug the pi's HDMI into the monitor (using the adapter) **before** turning the pi on and then turn on the monitor and then the pi and it should work.

If it doesn't you may need to force the HDMI connection. Put the SD card in your computer and edit the config file in the boot partition, [as described here.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2171/75152)

[More ways to edit the HDMI configuration can be found here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) (Thanks, Jaromanda X.)

Comment: that's rather sparse info in that link ... https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md is where you get real information :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok.

Comment: Yep, monitor was not on first... Thanks, Del

Comment: @DelDavidson Does it work know? If so please could you accept the answer? This will finish the question and show other users that it has a solution.

Comment: @DelDavidson Please accept the answer by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

4:3 1280 x 1024 computer monitors will work because i have used my raspberry pi with a 4:3 1280 x 1024 computer monitor before and it works automatically with no configuration and i used a hdmi to vga adapter because my monitor was vga only

Comment: Agree. I use a screen with the same geometry and a simple HDMI to DVI cable